# Network connection dies after 10 seconds

Tags: windows-xp, networking, windows-networking

My Windows XP machine does not work properly anymore. Since the system got shutdown by either a power outage, or some updates have applied and the PC is restarted the network connection is showing weird things.

Normally, I had always an internet connection. Now, the internet connection doesn't work, I have to restart the network adapter and then it works for only 10 seconds. After the 10 seconds, I have to restart the adapter once again. I have no idea how this could happen.

I'm not able to ping my default gateway either (after the 10 seconds). I've tried rebooting the machine and installing SP3, both didn't work. I've tried to repair the connection aswell, it worked (for just 10 seconds) and then the connection dies again. Windows does show an "active connection" however pinging the default gateway nor other outbound connections work.

Does anyone have a clue on how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As continuing troubleshooting, i would UNINSTALL the network adapter and reboot, forcing windows to reinstall it. If that doesn't work, install a known working network adapter (i know most people may not have one laying around, but i always have a spare). This will tell us if its something with the network on the machine, or hardware related.

Do you have any antivirus or firewalls installed?

Comment: It's a virtual machine, so yes the physical does work. I will try to remove the adapter as you said.

Comment: Okay, done that. It has the name "LAN-connection 2", however it still has the same issues as before.

Comment: Including the fact that it is a virtual machine is a relatively large part of the equation, please edit your question accordingly. What HOST OS? WHat virtualization platform? Are the associated tools installed and up to date?